# Como reproduzir relacionamento em Objetos?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, modelo-relacional, java-8

Segundo a definição deste [site](https://sites.google.com/site/uniplibancodedados1/aulas/aula-6---cardinalidade-no-relacionamento):

> **CARDINALIDADE**
>
> É o número máximo e mínimo de ocorrências de uma entidade que estão
>   associadas às ocorrências de outra entidade que participa do
>   relacionamento. Ou seja, a cardinalidade é importante para ajudar a
>   definir o relacionamento, pois ela define o número de ocorrências em
>   um relacionamento.

Ela é muito usada em banco de dados relacional, e geralmente utiliza o identificador (PK) de uma tabela para definir o relacionamento entre tabelas através de suas chaves *PK (Primary Key) e FK (Foreign Key)*.

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber de que forma eu poderia reproduzir o relacionamento em *Objetos que representam minhas tabelas* programaticamente usando a orientação a objeto?

Para isso criei o seguinte exemplo para ilustrar a situação:

Classe `Produto` contendo os seguintes atributos:

```
private int idProduto;
private String descricao;
private double valor;
```

Classe `Pedido` contendo os seguintes atributos:

```
private int idPedido;
private double valorTotal;
```

Classe `PedidoItem` contendo os seguintes atributos:

```
private int idPedidoItem;
private int quantidade;
```

Suas respectivas cardinalidades são:

- **Pedido** 1:N **PedidoItem**
- **Produto** 1:1 **PedidoItem**

Eu sei que se pode utilizar os id's para determinar o relacionamento, porem não sei implementar na forma correta e gostaria de saber se existe outra forma de fazer isto.

Segue o código completo das três classes.

Classe `Produto`:

```
package cardinalidadeemobjeto;

public class Produto {
    private int idProduto;
    private String descricao;
    private double valor;

    public Produto(){}

    public int getIdProduto() {
        return idProduto;
    }

    public void setIdProduto(int idProduto) {
        this.idProduto = idProduto;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

Classe `Pedido`:

```
package cardinalidadeemobjeto;

public class Pedido {
    private int idPedido;
    private double valorTotal;

    public Pedido(){}

    public int getIdPedido() {
        return idPedido;
    }

    public void setIdPedido(int idPedido) {
        this.idPedido = idPedido;
    }

    public double getValorTotal() {
        return valorTotal;
    }

    public void setValorTotal(double valorTotal) {
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
    }        
}
```

Classe `PedidoItem`:

```
package cardinalidadeemobjeto;

public class PedidoItem {
    private int idPedidoItem;
    private int quantidade;

    public PedidoItem(){}

    public int getIdPedidoItem() {
        return idPedidoItem;
    }

    public void setIdPedidoItem(int idPedidoItem) {
        this.idPedidoItem = idPedidoItem;
    }

    public int getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(int quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }

}
```

Comment: Uma dúvida. Você não vai utilizar JPA?

Comment: Não vou usar nenhuma API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar composição de classe com List para multiplos valores

Exemplo:

> Pedido 1:N PedidoItem

Em sua classe Pedido, você teria:

```
public class Pedido {
    private int idPedido;
    private double valorTotal;
    private List<PedidoItem> pedidoItem = new ArrayList<PedidoItem>();
```

Para

> Produto 1:1 PedidoItem

Você teria então

```
public class Produto {
    private int idProduto;
    private String descricao;
    private double valor;
    private PedidoItem pedidoItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

classe PedidoItem deverá conter um atributo do tipo produto

```
public class PedidoItem{
    ...
    private Produto produto;
    ...
```

classe Pedido tem uma lista de PedidoItem

```
public class Pedido{
   ...
   private List<PedidoItem> pedidoItems;
   ...
```

Se pretende fazer um relacionamento BIDIRECIONAL

Coloque um atributo do tipo PedidoItem no Produto

Coloque um atributo do tipo Pedido em PedidoItem